# Automatically Refresh Excel Data Connections

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-query

I have a data file that has two Microsoft Query Connection Queries that pull data from an outside source. My goal is for these connections to update automatically within my local Microsoft Excel application. I have uploaded this Excel file on to the online version of Microsoft Excel, thus when it updates automatically in my local Microsoft Excel version, it will update the online version.

This refresh needs to be done independent of use of the system, meaning that no person will need to open the file or refresh the file, the local Excel version needs to not be opened by a person, but could be by some sort of code.

I have tried using the automatic refresh after [x] minutes, but that will only update when I open my local version AND that amount of time has passed. I do not want to have to open the local data source, because the eventual goal is to have a separate system that will update this in the background, that I do not manage at all.

If you have any advice on how to make this work, that would be great!

Comment: "My goal is for these connections to update automatically within my local Excel application." ........ "no person will need to open the file or refresh the file, the local excel version needs to not be opened". Just struggling to make sense of this - Are you expecting a program to perform an action when it isn't running?

Comment: I want the program to just be independent, I do not want a person to have to open the file. If code has to open the file and update from there, that is kind of what I am going for. I see where the confusion is, I added to the line, saying that it just needs to not be opened manually.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to have a program or service running all the time in the background.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will update the online version." Please describe how many documents you are talking about, where they live, and what the experience is you are trying to create.

Comment: So I have a OneDrive file that has the automatic save on the Excel File. The ODBC connection usually pulls about 400 rows of data, about 4000 data points in total whenever I call the query. The file lives on OneDrive, where I can access them from another computer. I basically want it so that the ODBC connections refresh automatically once a day, and then upload the new data to the online version of Excel. This file is already on the online version of excel and I have noticed that if you make a change to the local/OneDrive version of the file, then those changes get uploaded online.